# Shuffling doesn't actually save into array?

Tags: bash

I'm new to shell script and am having an issue with the shuf function.
This is my code

```
declare -a myarray=( 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E' 'F' )
myarray = $(shuf -e "${myarray[@]}")
echo "$myarray"
```

I make an array containing the six characters. I then shuffle them randomly, and print them out. My issue is that if I were to add another line, for example

```
echo ${myarray[2]}
```

This doesn't actually print the randomly sorted character in the 3rd position. Instead, it will always print 'C'. How can I actually save the sorted array? Do I need to make another array?

Thank you very much

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in bash are defined with `()`. Bash is not statically typed, so setting `myarray` equal to some output of characters will do just that, making it a string you can echo with `echo $myarray` to see the full output.

You need to wrap your output in parens to make it clear to bash that your new `myarray` should also be an array:

```
myarray=($(shuf -e "${myarray[@]}"))
```

Comment: ... and there must be no blanks around `=`.